# Jquery how to detect which event was fired when binding to multiple events

Tags: jquery

I am binding an element to multiple events like this:

```
$(document).on('paste click cut', '.inputItemName', function() {...});
```

and inside the function i want to use a switch-case statement on the event that was triggered. How do I do that?